# Can't open another .py file after execute by Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, psutil

i use `from psutil import Popen` to open another .py file:

```
Popen('python file2.py', shell=True)
```

But when i click the button (Tkinter) to open that file/widget (file2.py) in file1.exe after execute by pyinstaller. I can't open it, and it doesn't seem to work, can't link. Pyinstaller doesn't wrap all files and link them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below steps for converting python file to exe:

```
Open cmd prompt and type:
pip install pyinstaller
once installed open the folder where the file has to be converted and open comd window(shift + right key) type:
pip install pyinstaller (2 folders will be created)
To further reduce it:
pyinstaller -w -F modA.py (This will create single exe file)
```

Followed by Use "subprocess" to open the file:

```
    wrapper = ['python', 'Wrapper.py',IPdirpath, OPdirpath]
    result = subprocess.Popen(wrapper,  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = result.communicate()
    status_wrapper=out.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: what are `IPdirpath`, `OPdirpath`?

Comment: Those are arguments if you want to pass. You can omit it.